# How to code website with GoogleEarth API plugin that depicts multiple KMZ files that can be toggled through by user?

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth-plugin

So I am currently trying to create a webpage, where the user can toggle between KMZ (there will be 8) files (which depict colour coded maps of Canada made in GIS then converted to KMZ).  What I would like this website to look like can be seen at www.mapathy.ca, but with the toggle option on there! This is where I am having issues, I can find similar questions where there is code options for making a toggle for these KMZ layers, but I am unable to in put them into my existing html file. Whenever I try to I seem to make the GoogleEarth window that is currently there disappear altogether. I am going to include my entire HTML as it stands currently. I appreciate any insight very much!!

```
 <!doctype html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=News+Cycle:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

      <title>Mapathy</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>


      <style>
        /* normalize.css 2011-06-23T00:50 UTC //github.com/jonathantneal/normalize.css */
        article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}html{cursor:default;font-size:100%;overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body,form,input,button,select,textarea{font-size:100%;margin:0}a,a:active,a:hover{outline:none}a:focus{outline:thin dotted}abbr{_border-bottom:expression(this.title ? '1px dotted':'none')}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}pre,code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;_font-family:'courier new',monospace;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word}q{quotes:none}q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}small,sub,sup{font-size:75%}sub,sup{line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}nav ul{list-style:none}audio[controls],canvas,video{display:inline-block;*display:inline}audio{display:none;_display:expression(this.controls ? 'inline':'none');*zoom:1}audio[controls]{display:inline-block}img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}svg:not(:root){ overflow:hidden}legend{*margin-left:-7px}button,input,select,textarea{vertical-align:baseline;*vertical-align:middle}button,input{line-height:normal;_overflow:expression(this.type == 'button|reset|submit' ? 'visible':'')}button,input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{overflow:visible;-webkit-appearance:button}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{ -webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
        body {
            color: #151412;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
        h2{
            font-size: 36px;
        }
        p {
            line-height: 1.4;
        }
        img.profile1 {
            border: 1px solid #4C4B47;
            width: 200px;
            height:200px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 5px; 
        }
        img.GE2008 {
            border: 3px solid #4C4B47;
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;


        }

        img.favourite {
            border: 2px solid #4C4B47;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 15px;


        }
        img.logo {
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
        }

        section.banner {
            padding-top: 100px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
            background-image: url('images/tweed.png');
            text-align: center;
        }
        section.banner h1 {
            font-size: 45px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        section.banner h2 {
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        script.map {
            background-image: #000;
            float: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            border: 300px solid #4C4B47;
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;

        }
        section.about {
            background-image: #000;
            float: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;

        }
        section.moreinfo {
            background-image: #000;
            float: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }

        script.map {
            text-align: center;
        }

        section.about h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        section.contact {
            background-image: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }

        section.social {
            background-image: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }

        section.favourites {
            background-image: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }
        section.box {
            padding: 50px 100px;
        }
        section.banner {
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
            font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;
        }
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #434A5C;
            background: #ffffff;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .menu li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 20px 35px;
        }

        .menu a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333333;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: 'News Cycle', sans-serif;

        }




      </style>
    </head>

    <body>





        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#moreinfo">More Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#favourites">Favourites</a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class= "banner"> 

            <h1>Mapathy</h1>
            <h2>A re-conceptualization of the declining voter turnout rates in Canada</h2>
        </section>



    <div class="map" id="map3d"></div>


      <script class="map" type="text/javascript">
        var ge;
        google.load("earth", "1", {"other_params":"sensor=false"});

        function init() {
          google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
        }

        function initCB(instance) {
          ge = instance;
          ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

          addKmlFromUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/mapathy2/kmz-files/1988eqintkmz.kmz?attredirects=0&d=1');
    }
        function addKmlFromUrl(kmlUrl) {
      var link = ge.createLink('');
      link.setHref(kmlUrl);

      var networkLink = ge.createNetworkLink('');
      networkLink.setLink(link);
      networkLink.setFlyToView(true);

      ge.getFeatures().appendChild(networkLink);
    }

        function failureCB(errorCode) {
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);


      </script>



        <section id= "about" class= "about box">
        <h2>About this project</h2>
            <p>The following maps depict the declining voter turnout rate being witnessed in Canada. Voter turnout refers to the percentage of eligible voters who cast a ballot in an election. Areas marked white (1.00), are where 54% or less of eligible voters cast a ballot, areas marked grey (2.00), are where between 55-74% of eligible voters cast a ballot, and areas marked black (3.00), are where 75% or more eligible voters cast a ballot. </p>

        </section>



        <section id= "moreinfo" class= "moreinfo box">
            <h3>More Information</h3>
            <a href="http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=vot&document=index&lang=e">Elections Canada Official Information for Voters </a>
            <p>for more information on the voting process & ways to vote in Canada</p>
            <a href="http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=ele&document=index&lang=e">Elections Canada Past Elections </a> 
            <p>to learn more about historical voter turnout rates.</p>
        </section>
        <section id= "contact" class= "contact box"> 
            <h4>Contact Owner</h4>
            <img src="images/profile1.png" class="profile1">
        </section>
        <section class= "social box">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/akrichardson"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
            <a href="http://ca.linkedin.com/in/annerichardson1"><img src="images/linkedin.png"></a>
            <p>Note: This webpage is part of a final Master's Research project for the Communication and Culture program at Ryerson University. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </section>  


        <section id="favourites" class= "favourites box">
            <h4>My Favourite Things</h4>
            <img src="images/empirebiscuit.jpg" class="favourite">
            <img src="images/candy.jpg" class="favourite">
            <img src="images/algonquin.jpg" class="favourite">
        </section>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KML files that are pre-made and do not change in real time it is much easier to use fetchKML to toggle ON and OFF rather than use networkLink (as you are doing)

look at this Google demo

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#fetch_kml_(interactive,_checkboxes)

Comment: hi @lifeisGood thank you for your response! When I try and add this code to my existing html, no google earth loads whatsoever...is there somewhere/way I should specifically be adding the code found via that link to my project? thanks again

Comment: why don't you click the 'edit html' button on the link I gave. then use that html code as the base for your page, modifying it as you wish. In your current code you load the GE javascript halfway down your html code, when it should be loaded at the top of it within the <head> part